# Using bash script with awk as command

Tags: bash, awk

I was learning `awk` from [here](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

There it gives:

**column.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
column="$1"
awk '{print '"$column"'}'
```

But then doing following gave me error:

```
$ ls -l | column 3 
column: 3: No such file or directory
```

How can use column.sh as command?

Comment: IMHO experts never advise to parse output of `ls` command. Please do add more information in your question that what is your ultimate goal which you are trying to achieve by this script.

Comment: You have piped the output of `ls` command to `column` command. Please see `man column` for more details on that command.

Comment: `column` is an external command (see `man column`) and that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: `awk -v column="$1" '{print $column}'`??

Comment: But then, how the linked page able to [run it](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-4) directly as `ls -l | column 3`?

Comment: `awk '{print $'"$column"'}'` -- see further down the page.

Comment: Please don't learn `awk` from that page. Some very good references can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info). The page [awk one-liners explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one/) is a very good start!

Comment: If you meant to pass the output from `ls` to `column.sh`, you have to use the full name - `column` != `column.sh`.

Answer (score 4):

> **Question:** How can use column.sh as command?

---

Use `column.sh` as a command. Obviously, `column` is not `column.sh`.

So you may:

```
/the/directory/with/the/script/column.sh 3
# or
cd /the/directory/with/the/script
./column.sh 3
```

Alternatively, you may add the path to the script to `PATH` environment variable. Or you may add the script to one of the paths already existing in `PATH`.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/the/directory/with/the/script"
column.sh 3
```

User scripts are typically installed in `$HOME/bin` or, you may follow the extension to xdg-user-dirs specification, use `$HOME/.local/bin` directory or for all users in `/usr/local/bin`.

---

**Note:** an update of your script should read:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ "$1" =~ [^0-9] ]] || exit 1
awk -v c="$1" '{print $c}'
```

Comment: But then, how the linked page able to [run it](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-4) directly as `ls -l | column 3`?

Comment: Note you will also need to make your script executable with `chmod +x column.sh`. Only necessary one time.

Comment: @anir Apparently the sentence _Only one problem: the script doesn't work_ extends beyond it's inteded range...

Comment: @anir the page you reference is wrong, you have to call it with `ls -l | ./column.sh 3` or `ls -l | /path/to/column.sh 3` and this will only work if `column.sh` has the executable flag set per comment of @MarkSetchell

Comment: `how the linked page able to run it directly as ls -l | column 3?` Well, the site is a (good) introduction to awk, so I guess it omits (rightfully) information about how shell works. I see there is a short explanation about `chmod +x` in one chapter and about installing to `$HOME/bin` directory, but nothing more. I guess the author didn't concern himself with such details, concentrating rather on explaining awk.